# Amazon green grass basicdiscovery.py sample is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-greengrass

I am following docs given at: 
**https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/module4.html**

Following I have tried:

- 1. Created a group
  2. Created a core
  3. Created 2 devices as per the above docs
  4. Created subscription
  5. Run the greengrass core on my linux machine. Just modified the config.json to use 443 port for MQTT and HTTP
  6. Deployed the group to core device. till now it is successful.
- On another linux machine downloaded all certificates and trying to run the basicdiscovery.py as per the guide.

*But getting following error while doing discovery:*

```
2019-12-24 13:22:35,232 - AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.greengrass.discovery.providers - INFO - Starting discover request...
2019-12-24 13:22:35,232 - AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.greengrass.discovery.providers - INFO - Endpoint: xyz-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
2019-12-24 13:22:35,232 - AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.greengrass.discovery.providers - INFO - Target thing: pub
2019-12-24 13:22:35,232 - AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.greengrass.discovery.providers - DEBUG - Creating tcp connection...
2019-12-24 13:22:35,275 - AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.greengrass.discovery.providers - DEBUG - Creating ssl connection...
2019-12-24 13:22:36,090 - AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.greengrass.discovery.providers - DEBUG - Matching host name...
2019-12-24 13:22:36,090 - AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.greengrass.discovery.providers - DEBUG - Sending discover request: GET /greengrass/discover/thing/pub HTTP/1.1
Host: xyz-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
2019-12-24 13:22:36,091 - AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.greengrass.discovery.providers - DEBUG - Receiving discover response header...
2019-12-24 13:22:36,540 - AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.greengrass.discovery.providers - DEBUG - Receiving discover response body...

Error in discovery!

Type: <class 'AWSIoTPythonSDK.exception.AWSIoTExceptions.DiscoveryDataNotFoundException'>

Error message: No discovery data found


9/10 retries left
Backing off...
2019-12-24 13:22:36,541 - AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.protocol.connection.cores - DEBUG - backOff: current backoff time is: 1 sec.
```

I did not find similar issue on web, that is why seeking help on stack overflow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to try this 1st: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/quick-start.html

Comment: Did you solved it? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port number from 443 to 8883

Comment: And why change the port number? Can you explain it why port 8883 better is as port 443?